# Python throwing variable scope error in Django app

Tags: python, django, web-deployment

I am currently working on a small Library management Django app, the following is one the view function

```
def issue_book(request):
    now = datetime.now()
    if now.month < 10:
        month = "0" + str(now.month)
    if now.day < 10:
        day = "0" + str(now.day)
    today = str(now.year) + "-" + month + "-" + day
    context = {
        'today': today
    }
    return render(request, 'admin_area/issue_book.html', context)
```

But this gives me an error as shown:

```
UnboundLocalError at /admin_area/issue_book
local variable 'day' referenced before assignment
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin_area/issue_book
Django Version: 3.2
Exception Type: UnboundLocalError

Exception Value:    local variable 'day' referenced before assignment
```

Can anyone explain the cause of the error!

Comment: What would you want to return if both 'if conditions' fail? if no month and no day < 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that both `day` and `month` are not set i.e undefined when greater than 10:

You could have:

```
def issue_book(request):
    now = datetime.now()
    month = "0" + str(now.month) if now.month < 10 else str(now.month)       
    day = "0" + str(now.day) if now.day < 10 else str(now.day)        
    today = str(now.year) + "-" + month + "-" + day
    ...
```

You can also have:

```
def issue_book(request):
    now = datetime.now()
    today = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    context = {
        'today': today
    }
...
```

For formatting strftime:
https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strftime

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are trying to return 01,02,...10,11,12 etc?

try this:

```
   def issue_book(request):
        now = datetime.now()
        month = now.month
        day = now.day
        if month < 10:
            month = "0" + str(month)
        if day < 10:
            day = "0" + str(day)
        today = str(now.year) + "-" + month + "-" + day
        context = {
            'today': today
        }
        return render(request, 'admin_area/issue_book.html', context)
```

I would prefer using strftime rather than doing the above:

```
def issue_book(request):
    today = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    context = {
        'today': today
    }
    return render(request, 'admin_area/issue_book.html', context)
```